# How can I stop reloadData on my UITableView from clearing the delete confirmation button?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

So I have the following:

- A UITableView with deletable cells (the kind where you swipe the cell then click the delete button)
- The UITableView's properties (eg. a UILabel) are automatically updated (with a `reloadData` call on the UITableView) every second by a NSTimer (this is required)

The problem is that the `reloadData` call clears the delete button after swiping (within a second of course). How can I keep this from happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I need to do was to set the UILabels text property from the NSTimers invocation method call and it doesn't even require a `reloadData` call to update the UILabel...

Answer (score 1):

u can keep a boolean flag variable that becomes true if the delete button is visible and false if not and in the place where u call reloadData u can check the flag value and function accordingly

Answer (score 0):

When the user swipes a `UITableViewCell`, `tableView`'s `isEditing` property will be set to `YES`. You should check this property before you reload your table.